# How to restore/setup debian-sys-maint user and scripts for mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, debian

I recently installed mysql 5.7 on ubuntu-20.04, but the debian-sys-maint user and config appears to be missing.  Can anyone explain how to restore it or set it up?  It's my understanding that user is supposed to be the one used for startup, shutdown, and other maintenance functions.  I've tried doing a reinstall:

```
# apt reinstall mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04' (MySQL:repo.mysql.com [amd64]) for 'mysql-community-server'
Selected version '5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04' (MySQL:repo.mysql.com [amd64]) for 'mysql-server'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 39.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 mysql-community-server amd64 5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04 [39.8 MB]
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 mysql-server amd64 5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04 [69.5 kB]
Fetched 39.9 MB in 1s (35.9 MB/s)  
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 102617 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-community-server_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
.
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) over (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) over (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.17) ...
root@xblgx-ops-4:~# ls /etc/mysql
conf.d  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback  mysql.cnf  mysql.conf.d
```

Note there is no /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

I can create the user easily enough, but I'm concerned about getting any scripts installed and settings configured which might be needed to get it to do whatever it's supposed to be doing.